# BCryptPasswordEncoder works for more than 72 bytes, how?

Tags: java, spring-security, bcrypt

Just notice something interesting, and didn't found any explanation online,

bcrypt normal implementation is limited to 72 bytes length input [stack exchange link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length)

BCryptPasswordEncoder works correctly for any length(I have tried a 200 length string), but no info is provided on how,

can someone explain this? does the BCryptPasswordEncoder pre-hash(I tried diving into the implementation but didn't found any indication of pre hash... )?

Comment: @eis, 
 apologies, you are correct, it is cropped, closing as duplicate